# QBChat/XEP-0045/ leavRoom automatically after coming back from backbround? (Quickblox)

Tags: quickblox

When coming back from background, our app automatically reconnects to chat server and enters a room.

All goes well and the chat room history is loaded successfully. But all of a sudden we receive "QBChat/XEP-0045/ leavRoom" and can't send messages to room because "room is not joined".

Any thoughts on why this behaviour accours?

Comment: Do you use ARC or not?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use the next logic:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) QBChatRoom *testRoom;
```

**Join**

```
[[QBChat instance] setDelegate:self];

[[QBChat instance] createOrJoinRoomWithName:@"myRoom" membersOnly:NO persistent:YES];


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark QBChatDelegate

- (void)chatRoomDidEnter:(QBChatRoom *)room{
    // retain current room
    self.testRoom = room;
}
```

**Leave**

```
[[QBChat instance] leaveRoom:testRoom];

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark QBChatDelegat

- (void)chatRoomDidLeave:(NSString *)roomName{
    // release room
    self.testRoom = nil;
}
```

I think your issue is with  **self.testRoom = nil;**, you don't do it. But you should.
Try this suggestion.

http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios#Joining.2Fleaving_rooms